# Only getting a single value from predict.nls - why?

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I'm running the folllowing to get predicted/fitted values:

```
library(RCurl)
data <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/a8a6644a639c35ceb9d9/raw/5b7c13bbcd439dacbca70e07c96b6c33804273d2/data.csv")
object <- read.csv(text = data)
mod <- nls(formula = "solution_complexity ~ problem_complexity", data=object, start = list(problem_complexity=0))
predict(mod)
```

However, this only gives me a single value. How can I get all the predicted values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do

```
predict(mod, newdata = object[, "problem_complexity", drop = FALSE])

[1]  2  6  4  3  3  4  8 16  7  5  3 12  4  3  9  2  1  5  1  1  4  6  2  5
```

it appears to work.

Comment: These are just the raw data observations - that can't be the predictions?

Comment: @histelheim try predicting for different `x`? Predictions can be same as raw values when there is little or no variation or model overfits.